# Bash CLI variable substitution and piping in package.json script

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, package.json

In my package.json script (this is probably a general bash issue but this is my scenario) I have a script command:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test ava $1 --tap | tnyan"
```

If I call it:

```
yarn test foo
```

It does not work (it runs every test).

This works:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test ava $1"
yarn test foo
```

And so does:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test ava foo --tap | tnyan"
 yarn test
```

Probably answered a million times but I can't seem to phrase things well enough to get a Google match for this issue.

How do I get CLI substitution to work when piping?

Comment: What do you mean, "CLI substitution"?

Comment: Oh, you mean the `$1`. That can only see arguments passed to the `sh -c` instance that node starts. If node doesn't pass any arguments through, your script can't see 'em.

Comment: I mean substituting $1 for my CLI parameter.

Comment: ...which is to say this problem centers on whatever node.js code is invoking the shell in question.

Comment: That said, are you willing to consider other approaches? If you don't want to patch the aforementioned tooling, you might have better luck passing the value through an environment variable. That is, `run_only_test=foo yarn test`, and then in your file `NODE_ENV=test ava $run_only_test`

Comment: Ah I see. Prob not worth it. Merely curious as to why I could not get it to work but not worth modifying things

Comment: Mind you, the above was assuming that `yarn` *is* invoking a shell. It'd be interesting to have a more conclusive take on this -- if you were to, say, `strace -e execve -f -s 2048 yarn test foo`, that should provide enough information to be able to respond with less guesswork.

Comment: Now I can use $1 fine - just not with the pipe.

Comment: Right -- that's why I was wondering if yarn was maybe trying to implement its own shell-like behavior rather than implementing a real one, because a genuine POSIX-compliant shell wouldn't care about whether there's a pipe in place. The requested `strace` logs should settle the matter -- we'll see if it's invoking a shell, and we'll see what arguments that shell is passed. (I'm actually more of a fan of [Sysdig](https://www.sysdig.org/) than `strace` -- if you have it handy in your environment, let me know and I'll provide a query).

Comment: BTW, if you don't want to take it on my word that a shell handles the case correctly (when correctly invoked), you can invoke it yourself: `sh -c 'NODE_ENV=test ava "$1" --tap | tnyan' _ foo`

Comment: Hmm no strace on OSX. But yes it works with the CLI version you posted. No biggy - I guess I'll do without piping

Comment: Huh. There's traditionally a `truss` tool there that's about equivalent (maybe replaced by `dtruss` on newer versions?), but I don't know its usage well enough to provide detailed guidance.

Comment: Me neither. Thanks for the input though. Had me baffled.